# Probleme with QThread and Python decorator

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I've got a problem with my code about Qthread with PyQt on Python 3.6
Error is File

```
F:\PROGRAMMES\Qt\Projet\cYrAnalyzer\worker2.py", line 14, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: execute_this_function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[Finished in 3.1s with exit code 3221226505]
```

This is the class worker2.py :

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from functools import wraps

class Runner(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)


def run(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
         runner = Runner(func, *args, **kwargs)
         func.__runner = runner
         runner.start()
    return async_func
```

this is the main class :

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import gui, os, time
from worker2 import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = gui.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.compteur.clicked.connect(self.execute_this_function)

    @run
    def execute_this_function(self):
        self.ui.edit_compteur.setText("1")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.ui.edit_compteur.setText("2")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.ui.edit_compteur.setText("3")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.ui.edit_compteur.setText("4")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.ui.edit_compteur.setText("5")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

ERROR :

```
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: execute_this_function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: some feedback??

Answer (score 0):

The error that you indicate is caused because clicked is an overloaded signal, that is to say in reality they are 2 signals, one with a boolean signature and another without a signature: `clicked = pyqtSignal([], [bool])` and by default it will try to pass the boolean. So the solution is to establish the slot signature using `@pyqtSlot`

The other error that is still not shown due to the previous error is that you should not update the GUI directly. A simple strategy is to use `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` next to functools.partial if you need to pass extra arguments.

```py
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from functools import partial

from worker2 import run
import gui


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = gui.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.compteur.clicked.connect(self.execute_this_function)

    @run
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def execute_this_function(self):
        wrapper = partial(self.ui.edit_compteur.setText, "1")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        wrapper = partial(self.ui.edit_compteur.setText, "2")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        wrapper = partial(self.ui.edit_compteur.setText, "3")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        wrapper = partial(self.ui.edit_compteur.setText, "4")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        wrapper = partial(self.ui.edit_compteur.setText, "5")
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```